# What did Adi shankara tell about jagat in bhashya granthas?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras

Many people talk about jagat which is mentioned in prakarana grantha. I would like to know what Jagadguru Adi Shankaracharya has said about jagat in bhashya granthas like Brahma Sutra bhashya, Bhagavad Gita bhashya , Upanishad Bhashya.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on jagat (universe) in Brahma Sutra I.i.2.

> *That (is Brahman) from which (are derived) the birth etc. of this
> (universe).*

**Brahma Sutra I.i.2**

> ..............
>
> (So the meaning of this whole aphorism is):That omniscient and
> omnipotent source must be Brahman from which occur the birth,
> continuance, and dissolution of this universe that is manifested
> through name and form, that is associated with diverse agents and
> experiences, that provides the support for actions and results, having
> well-regulated space, time and causation, and that defies all thoughts
> about the real nature of its creation.
>
> Birth, continuance and dissolution only are mentioned here, since the
> other modifications [Growth, transformation and decay] that things are
> heir to are included in them. Had the six modifications [Birth,
> continuance, growth, transformation, decay and death] listed by Yaska
> in the words "It originates, exists, grows," etc. been accepted
> (here), it might lead to the doubt that the origin, existence, and
> destruction of the universe from the primary source (Brahman) are not
> referred to, these modifications being possible only during the
> continuation of the universe. In order that this doubt may not arise,
> the origin that takes place from Brahman, and the consequence and
> merger that occur in That Itself are referred to.
>
> Apart from God, possessed of the qualifications already
> mentioned, the universe, as described, cannot possibly be thought of
> as having its origin etc. from any other factor, e.g., Pradhana
> (primordial Nature) which is insentient, or from atoms, or
> non-existence, or some soul under worldly conditions (viz
> Hiranyagarbha). Nor can it originate spontaneously; for in this
> universe, people (desirous of products) have to depend on specific
> space, time, and causation. Those who stand by God (e.g. the
> Naiyayikas) rely on this very inference alone for establishing the
> existence etc. of God as distinguished from a transmigrating soul.

**Brahma Sutra Bhasya I.i.2 of Sri Sankaracharya translated by Swami Gambhirananda**

Answer (score -2):

Shankaracharya writes in his *Srih Jivamuktananda-lahari* verse 20, The Wave of Bliss of the Liberated While Alive (published in *Advaita-Prakarana-Manjari: A Bouquet of Non-Dual Texts* translators Dr. H. Ramamoorthy and Nome:

> brahma-satyam jagan-mithya jivo brahmaiva naparah
> anena vedyam sacchastram-iti vedanta-dindimah
>
> Brahman is the truth, the universe [jagat] is false,
> The jiva (individual self) is, indeed, Brahman, not another;
> By this should be known the Truth of the scripture;
> Thus is the drum-beat of Vedanta.

in the same publication with the translation of Sankaracharya's *Advaitanubhuti*, verses 3-4:

> aksi-dosa-vihinanam-eka eva yatha sasi
> maya-dosa-vihinanam-atmaiv-aikas-tatha sada
>
> Just as, for the those devoid of a defect in the eye,
> The moon is only one,
> Likewise, for those devoid of the defect of delusion,
> The Self [Atman], indeed, is ever One.
>
> dvitvam bhaty-aksi-dosena candre sve mayaya jagat
> dvitvam mrsa yatha candre mrsa dvaitam tath-atmani
>
> Being two appears due to a defect in the eye, in the case of the moon;
> So, by its own delusion, [does] the world (the universe) [jagat].
> Just as being two is false in the case of the moon,
> So, likewise, duality is false in the case of the Self [Atman].

The jagat is unreal, Brahman alone is real.

Comment: I told about give explanation form bhashya like bhagavad Gita bhashya upanishad bhashya Brahma sutra bhashya

Comment: Don't translate mithya as false. There is no word for it in English.